# Need suggestion on implement binary tree UI using Dojo

Tags: user-interface, tree, dojo, binary-tree

I have a binary tree data structure defined in ORM, and the data is stored in the database. Now I'm going to code a interactive UI logic representing the Tree using Dojo. I'm a newbie in Dojo area. Does anybody can give me suggestion which Dojo technique should I use for this purpose? I have looked at the Dojox.collections.BinaryTree, but it looks like a data structure in the Dojo Tool kit. What I want is some kind of widget then I just feed the data to it and then I can program

Answer (score 0):

you can create Dojo tree very easily.
Look Here: [Dojo tree](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Tree)
There are more examples here too: [see here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tree-examples.html)

When you fetch something from the database it would be good to convert it to JSON, in order to wrap the JSON into an ItemReadStore (see the examples I have posted)